# Nested Fragment pager .setCurrentItem not working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, callback, android-viewpager

I have a Fragment in my ViewPager wich has a DatePicker, if the user selects a date from the picker he is returning it via a callback to the Activity.

The activity gets the ViewPagerContainer of the fragment and set the pager to another day according the date.

The function in the container fragment is succesfully reached and it logs the right day number, but the pager is not updated it stays on the same page... no crashes or something..

My code:

**MainAcitivty** (calls containerfragment)

```
 public void onDatumSelected(int days) {
    RoosterPagerContainer positionRooster = (RoosterPagerContainer) fragmentje;
    positionRooster.updatePager(days);

}
```

fragmentje is set on navigationDrawer select..

```
 case 0:
                getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_time);
                fragment = new RoosterPagerContainer();//this is the contianer
                this.fragmentje = fragment;
```

**ContainerFragment** (set pager not working)

```
    @InjectView(R.id.vp_pages) ViewPager pager;
    public CarouselActivity theActivitiy;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)       {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roosterfragment_container, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);

        pager.setAdapter(buildAdapter());
        pager.setCurrentItem(5000, false);
        pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

        return view;
    }
    public void updatePager(int days)
    {
        Log.e(String.valueOf(days), "This is logged but the pager dont switch???");
        //pager.post(new Runnable() {
          //  public void run() {
                pager.setCurrentItem((5000 + days), true);
                pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
         //   }
      //  });

    }
    private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
        return(new BootstrapPagerAdapter(theActivitiy, getChildFragmentManager()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            theActivitiy = (CarouselActivity) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " ik snap er niks van");
        }

    }
```

**ChildofContainerFragment** (Calls mainacitivty)

```
 OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    public void onDatumSelected(int days);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(CalendarDatePickerDialog dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    DateTime selectednow = DateTime.forDateOnly(year, (monthOfYear+1), dayOfMonth);
    DateTime today = DateTime.now(TimeZone.getDefault());
    //if(!(selectednow.isSameDayAs(selected)))
    //

    int days = (selectednow.getModifiedJulianDayNumber() - today.getModifiedJulianDayNumber());
    mCallback.onDatumSelected(days);
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) throws ClassCastException {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

public class BootstrapPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  {

```
public BootstrapPagerAdapter(final FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
   // this.ctxt = ctxt;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 10000;
}
///@Override
//public int getItemPosition(Object object){
   // return FragmentStatePagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
//}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    DateTime pagerdate = DateTime.now(TimeZone.getDefault());
    DateTime days = pagerdate.plusDays(position - 5000);

    Log.e("Datepager",String.valueOf(days));

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("date", days.format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString());

    RoosterFragment roosterFragment = new RoosterFragment();
    roosterFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return roosterFragment;
}
```

}

(i change somethings in this code when i post the others but stil the same problem..)

Also I use support for older android devices android.v4.Fragment etc..

Also I'm sure the int days is not zero but for example eight.

Comment: Can you post your BootstrapPagerAdapter?

Comment: Done! The setcurrentitem is onetime working in the onccreateview thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it's fixed fragmentje wat not set because if forget that i have it twice in my Navigation drawer so this was the fix..

```
   case 0:
                getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_time);
                fragment = new RoosterPagerContainer();
                this.fragmentje = fragment;
                break;
            case 1:
                getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_time);
                fragment = new RoosterPagerContainer();
                this.fragmentje = fragment;//this was not before...
                break;
```